# Is there a R function to get the result from the previous two adjacent values?

Tags: r

for example

`a <- c(7, 10, 5, 4, 11)`

and I would like to b as:

b[1] = 0,

b[2] = a[2] - a[1],

b[3] = a[3] - a[2],

b[4] = a[4] - a[3],

b[5] = a[5] - a[4]

is there a function to obtain these values automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `diff`

```
b <- c(0, diff(a))
```

---

Or another option is `lag` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
b <- a - lag(a, default = first(a))
```